# No Kernel Specs found in Atom Hydrogen

Tags: python, atom-editor, hydrogen

[image]

I tried to install Hydrogen into ATOM, but get No Kernel Specs found error.

I installed jupyter notebook via anaconda and previous ran a "conda install jupyter" in anacoda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a python file you’re trying to run?

In terminal what does `jupiter kernelspec list —json` give you?
If you open a Jupiter notebook can you open a python notebook and run that in a kernel?  In terminal `jupyter notebook`, then select python from new on top left of home page of jupyter.

Is the grammar for that file python or do you have magic python or something else installed? If there is a different grammar you will need to map in hydrogen settings, eg for magic python: `{“python”: “magicpython”}`